# Copying values from one table with blank cells in between to another table with no cells in between

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, lookup

I'll try and explain this as basically as possible. We have a long list-like table with dates in the first column for each working day then a list on individual piercings we have completed with their respective prices and then daily totals in this format:

```
Date      Piercing  Price   Daily Total
26/10/13  ear       £9.50
          navel     £30     £39.50
28/10/13  nose      £17.50  £17.50
29/10/13  ear       £9.50
          nipple    £25
          eyebrow   £25     £59.50
```

etc
etc

As you can see the column which holds the daily totals will have a lot of blank cells in between. So what we have done is made a separate sheet with a list of dates and are hoping to find some form of lookup function which can read the existing **"Daily total"** column and copy only the cells which have values over in order that they appear so they match up with the right dates like this:

```
26/10/13  £39.50
28/10/13  £17.50
29/10/13  £59.50
```

etc
etc

If anyone can lend me as easy way of achieving this I will be most grateful as neither of us are talented with writing our own functions or statement codes.

Comment: The way I typed out the table seems to have formatted to some kind of list in this post for some reason? :S

Comment: How is this all connected to MySQL??

Comment: That was just a suggested tag. I'm a complete novice with anything programming based in excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looking for a list of dates and daily totals, assuming the daily totals have already been calulated and you never have negative transactions then this should work

```
SELECT date, MAX(DailyTotal) FROM peircings GROUP BY date;
```

OR

```
SELECT date, DailyTotal FROM peircings WHERE DailyTotal!='';
```

It's hard to know which one might even help you without a better understanding of your database and how you want to use the data.